# How to implement the process of "Time Limit Exceeded" , "Runtime Error " verdicts in online judge's backend?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been working on developing an online judge for my university project in OOP course. In fact I am working on the checker part which take a submission and return the verdict as well as time elapsed to the host server.

I have done the `"Accepted"`,`"Wrong Answer "`,`"Compilation Error"` part; but I am having a difficult time in trying to implement `"Runtime error"` and `"Time Limit Exceeded"` using Java Multithreading and concurrency API's.

Can anyone suggest me how I can implement it properly?

If anyone has developed an online judge previously, it would be better for me if he shares his source code(in case it is open source).

P.S:The judge will run in Windows Environment.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: What is an online judge?

Comment: Runtime Error is usually all too easy to implement.

Comment: @JordanD
It is a site where algorithm related problems are stored and programmers try to solve the problem within a certain time limit .

i.e:
[link] www.uvaonlinejudge.org
[link] www.codechef.com

Comment: @ChrisGerken Can you help me regarding this?better if you post a source code.

Comment: Chris was probaly referring to [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10449)